# How to put content under certain headings

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

How to put content under certain headings? 
I have two methods to load data

first `axios.get('/api/get/headers')`

second `axios.get('api/get/contents')`

I have no idea how correctly this will be done, given that the headers can be different and the content is correspondingly too

table example

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="header in headers" :data-key="header.name">{{ header.title }}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr v-for="content in contents">
         <td :data-key="content.name"> {{content.title}}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

The global problem is that the content can be an array

Comment: There's no way we can help you without at least seeing what your current output looks like and what you want it to look like.

Comment: the table is the same as in the lower answer
I described in the comments

Comment: @Marty how to implement the substitution in the desired column by the name of the field in the object?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-page example of a way to use axios with Vue.js to get some simple content on the page. Does this help you get started?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app">
         <div class="header">{{headerText}}</div>
         <div class="content">{{contentText}}</div>
      </div>
   </body>
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: function () {
      return {
         headerText: '',
         contentText: ''
      }
   },

   mounted: function () {
      axios.get("/api/get/headers").then(response => {
         this.headerText = response;
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
      });

      axios.get("/api/get/content").then(response => {
         this.contentText = response;
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
      });
   }
});
</script>

</html>
```

Update:

For your specific example, could you go through the list of headers again and match the name property with the content name property, and then display the content? Like so:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="header in headers" :data-key="header.name">{{ header.title }}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr v-for="header in headers">
         <td :data-key="header.name"> {{getContent(header.name).title}}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>


<script>
...
    methods: {
        getContent(name) {
            for (var index in this.contents) {
                if (this.contents[index].name === name) {
                    return this.contents[index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
</script>
```

Comment: yes of course this part is understandable as it is realized and I did it already)

Comment: Ok great. How may we help you?

Comment: If you read the description, then I need to adjust the content on the table headings

Comment: for example, it comes to me in the header dataAction
I have to show in the content under this column the object dataAction

Comment: The statement "adjust the content on the table headings" is too vague for me to reply with an answer. Can you update the question with some example HTML and outline one or two scenarios that you would like to find solutions for?

Comment: I updated the question. There, if you notice I have headers and content. Now, I need to fix the content under the headers problem in that the first headers can be different, secondly the content is not on the list of headers in this whole problem

Comment: how to implement the substitution in the desired column by the name of the field in the object?

Comment: Thanks, Rai. I've updated my answer to address what I think is your question. Is this enough to help you continue your project?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'm sorry, I don't know how else to help.

Comment: and How to display key -> value instead of title ?